# Create different environment settings in pytest

Tags: python, environment-variables, pytest

I'm new to pytest. I want to create a test that will run on different environments. Each environment has it's own variables (base_url, ids etc.). I want to send the environment in the command line so the test will use the relevant variables. I thought of creating different kind of 'settings.py' for each environment with different postfixes. for example settings-dev.py, settings-qa.py etc. But I'm not sure how to tell the test which one to use, and what is the right way to do it in pytest.
In general (could be a different questions), how can I set this kind of 'global variables' to use in all tests?

Comment: Are you testing a django project or do you just want to reuse its settings pattern?

Comment: @hoefling - not django, just want to do something similar... could be any other good solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several packages that reimplement Django's settings system in the way it can be used in non-Django projects; here is an example using [`simple-settings`](https://pypi.org/project/simple-settings/):

```
# settings_dev.py
SPAM = 'eggs'
```

```
# settings_prod.py
SPAM = 'bacon'
```

```
# test_spam.py
from simple_settings import settings


def test_spam():
    assert settings.SPAM in ['eggs', 'bacon']
```

If passing the settings via environment variable, thins will work out of the box:

```
$ SIMPLE_SETTINGS=settings_dev pytest 
======================================== test session starts ========================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.6, pytest-4.0.2, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0
rootdir: /home/hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow/so-54159045, inifile:
collected 1 item                                                                                    

test_spam.py .                                                                                [100%]

===================================== 1 passed in 0.01 seconds ======================================
```

If you want to pass the settings via command line argument, you will need to make `--settings` arg known to `pytest`: create a `conftest.py` file with the following contents:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--settings', action='store')
```

Now `pytest` will recognize the `--settings` arg, but simply ignore it elsewhere.

```
$ pytest --settings=settings_prod
======================================== test session starts ========================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.6, pytest-4.0.2, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0
rootdir: /home/hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow/so-54159045, inifile:
plugins: xdist-1.25.0, metadata-1.7.0, html-1.19.0, forked-0.2
collected 1 item                                                                                    

test_spam.py .                                                                                [100%]

===================================== 1 passed in 0.01 seconds ======================================
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It looks good. Will try it and let you know

Comment: Glad I could help!